# Why won't typescript resolve return types from functions in an object literal declaration?

Tags: typescript

I have a little experiment in typescript, trying to set up a helper for laying out a route hierarchy.

```
const route = <TParams = {}, TChildren = {}>(path: string, children?: TChildren) => ({
  path,
  params: undefined as TParams,
  children
});
```

I would use it like so:

```
const routes = {
  LOGIN: route<MyParams>("/login", {
    REGISTER: route("/register")
  })
};
```

I would expect the type of `routes` to end up like this:

```
{
    LOGIN: {
        path: string;
        params: MyParams;
        children: {
            REGISTER: {
                path: string;
                params: {};
                children: {};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But instead, I get this:

```
{
    LOGIN: {
        path: string;
        params: MyParams;
        children: {}
    }
}
```

The type of `REGISTER` is returned correctly by the `route` function. E.g. I can assign `route("/register")` to a variable and it will have the correct type, but if I try to nest it in children, then `routes` just displays `REGISTER` as `any` instead.

If I get rid of the `MyParams` type argument, then it becomes:

```
{
    LOGIN: {
        path: string;
        params: {};
        children: {
            REGISTER: any;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and how to achieve my expected behavior?

I'm using Typescript 2.8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your problem is that, even with [default generic parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), TypeScript currently has an [all-or-nothing approach to generic parameter inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571).  If you specify some parameters and leave out others, those will get default values, not inferred ones.

This is where I usually suggest people use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to split a function apart into two functions, one of which you explicitly set parameters on, and the other you rely on inference for.  For example:

```
const route = <TParams>() => <TChildren>(path: string, children?: TChildren) => ({
  path,
  params: undefined! as TParams,
  children
});
```

In this case, `route` is a function that returns a function.  This is how you call it:

```
const routes = {
  LOGIN: route<MyParams>()("/login", {
    REGISTER: route()("/register")
  })
};
```

That extra call is a little weird, but let's inspect the type of `routes`:

```
{
  LOGIN: {
    path: string;
    params: MyParams;
    children: {
      REGISTER: any;
    } | undefined;
  };
}
```

It's great, right?  Note that you get `undefined` because `children` is optional, and therefore possibly `undefined`.

---

Oh, that `any` is still there.  Actually that just seems to be a [type display bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23897) where the IntelliSense gives up on processing types involving some amount of nested inference.  The actual type is calculated properly:

```
const children = routes.LOGIN.children;
```

If you inspect `children` it shows up as:

```
const children: {
  REGISTER: {
    path: string;
    params: {};
    children: {} | undefined;
  };
} | undefined
```

which is the right type.  The display bug is a shame, but if you know about it you can probably work around it.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer! The perfect storm of the display error and all-or-nothing generic defaults was quite confusing and you explained it well. I chose this answer because I ended up using the currying approach, hoping that the issue in Explosion Pills' answer gets pushed through.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported in TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571

You will have to specify both types. Currently if you specify one generic type it will use the type default rather than using inference -- that is to say you can't have it infer one generic type if you specify the other.

The only way around this is to specify both generic types or update the function to pass parameters as an argument so both types can be inferred.

```
const registerRoutes = {
  REGISTER: route("/register"),
};
const routes = {
  LOGIN: route<MyParams, typeof registerRoutes>("/login", registerRoutes)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's good to know they've thought of this and committed to implementing it. In the mean time, jcalz's suggestion to curry the functions will do.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work, because by defining your type with default type parameters, when you don't give a second parameter, it assumes its default value, `{}`. `{REGISTER: route('/register')}` is assignable to `{}`, so you don't get an error, but, of course, you lose the type information.

For it to work, you should let TypeScript infer what type is `TChildren`. But, if you remove the default param, you'll get an error because type params without defaults should be first. If you change the order, you won't be able to give `TParams` a value without giving one to `TChildren`. So, the best way for you is to let TypeScript infer both params instead of calling it with them. For that, you'll need to use a little trick, and pass an object with that type so it can be inferred. It can be an empty object:

```
const route = <TParams, TChildren>(type: TParams, path: string, children?: TChildren) => ({
  path,
  params: undefined as TParams,
  children,
});
```

And you can call it like:

```
const routes = {
  LOGIN: route({} as MyParams, "/login", {
    REGISTER: route({} as MyParams, "/register", null)
  })
};
```

Now, as @jcalz said, the type for `routes.LOGIN.children` is correctly inferred though it is not correctly displayed.

This solution is a bit more cumbersome, but works.

Comment: This answer was useful as a workaround, but I found jcalz's currying suggestion to be more aesthetically pleasing. Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: Yes, I liked it better, too, in the aesthetic sense, though, in the resulting JavaScript code, my workaround performs much better because it only calls one function, while his implies the invocation of two, only to get type information in TypeScript (there is no difference in JavaScript). Of course, the performance concerns are important only depending on how frequently you call this function.